# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

The app has always been working fine until today. I've just updated my phone to 4.4.4 (Cyanogenmod). I've also updated Eclipse' ADT plugin and android SDK to the latest versions.

com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment is definitely there under "Android Private Libraries" (screenshot below).

What I have tried:
Repeatedly clean google-play-services_lib and my project
Close and re-open Eclipse

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.0.5" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>-->

    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:name="com.fuzzybee7.application.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name="com.example.app.AboutActivity" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And screenshot showing the class is there:
[image]

And yes, I did add Google Play Services library project in case you wonder:
[image]

Comment: check your build path

Comment: Hi @Rod_Algonquin, everything seems normal. Anything particular I should dig deeper?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Never used eclipse again after that so don't know :(

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enabled offline work for gradle:
Goto File > Settings > Gradle

Deselect Offline Work.

Then confirm if you have latest version of google services mentioned as dependencies in project level build.gradle:
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'`

You can find latest version here:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/

Clean and build the project after gradle sync completes.

These steps solved a similar issue I'd with Google Maps which logged same `ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class “com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment”`